# Flat device tree - Hypervisor

Tags: tree, device, flat, hypervisor, device-tree

The flat device tree FDT is used to pass information about the platform  hardware to the kernel. Is it possible to set a hypervisor in complete control of the FDT and then let the hypervisor pass a virtual FDT to the kernel (kind of virtualizing the FDT's)? For instance, I want only a certain range of physical memory to be visible to the kernel.

In fact, is it safe that the FDT is visible to the guests especially if we are targeting a completely bare-metal hypervisor?